# Vue3 rendering a extensible list of async components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, vuejs3

Please can you help me solve this problem.
After long hours looking for an answer, I can't find a way to make this work. I'm really new to Vue.
let me explain a little more about it.

I have an asynchronous component that is created on call. It have a template that structures a form based in a JSON it recieves. This component is created OK and is loading in right way all the fields. This is the structure:

```
<template>
  <div class="constraint_supercontainer col-lg-12">    
    <form class="constraint_group" v-for="constraint in constraints.data.constraints" :key="constraint">
      <div class="constraint_field">
        <label class="constraint_label">{{constraint.label}}</label>
        <select class="constraint_select" v-bind:name="constraint.name" v-bind:id="constraint.name">
          <option value="" selected disabled>-- SELECCIONE --</option>
          <option v-for="value in constraint.values" :key="value" v-bind:value="value['value']">{{ value['label'] }}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
const api_route = "<api_route>";

export default {
  name: 'Constraint',
  async setup(){
    const response = await fetch(api_route+'get-conditions');
    const constraints = await response.json();

    return { constraints }; 
  } 
};
</script>
```

In this step, all is good. But in the main app constructor I need to have a way to create multiple instances of this component (Constraint) and render them in the same DOM element. I found the way to do this in Vue2 with the Vue.extend function, but now it doesn't exist anymore. In Vue3 this is working just for the first element, if I call the function again, it gives an error. This is the structure of my main component:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="toolbar">
      <button @click="add">Agregar grupo condicional</button>
    </div>
    <div id="constraints_list" ref="constraints_list">
      <div v-for="item in constraints_group" :key="item">
        <Suspense>
          <Constraint></Constraint>
        </Suspense>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Constraint from './components/Constraint'
import { h } from 'vue';

export default {
    name: 'app',
    components: { 
        Constraint 
    },
    data() {
      return {
        constraints_group: [],
        constraint_count: 0,
        constraint:{
            gender: null
        }
      }
    },
    mounted () {
      this.addConstraintBlock();
    },
    methods: {

      addConstraintBlock() {
          this.constraint_count++;
          let instance = h(Constraint);
          this.constraints_group.push(instance);
      }
    },
}
</script>
```

And this is the error when I try to create a second one:
[This is the error when I create the second component and try to do the same flow as the first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jyefq.png)

I found in this post
https://www.reddit.com/r/vuejs/comments/iwc7o4/vue3_what_happen_to_vueextend/
a man who "created a workaround of Vue.extend function", but the project doesn't works for me, it gives me the following error:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/mount-vue-component/dist/index.cjs.js 11:10
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11:10)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
|   let vNode = vue.createVNode(component, props, children);
>   if (app?._context) vNode.appContext = app._context;
|   if (el) vue.render(vNode, el);
|   else if (typeof document !== 'undefined' ) vue.render(vNode, el = document.createElement('div'));
```

I tried to figure out how to use that loader but, again, but no luck, even after I installed the loader (and many others), configured the babel.config.json (as I found), etc. Also tried to recreate the code is in the project, but doesn't work neither.

So, at this point, I have no more ideas. I tried to find more ways but everithing I've done, gives me an error. If anyone can give my an idea, a way to solve or something, I will be **very very** grateful.

Answer (score 1):

I feel this is not about Vue 3 but about Vue in general...

In Vue you almost never create components instances in `<script>` block (some people do but it's usually because they don't understand how Vue works). Vue is "declarative" and "data-driven" framework. It means your template output is driven by a data - you don't create components, you modify the data and template will generate components for you based on that data...

Check this simple examle:

```js
const piece = Vue.component('Piece', {
  props: ['number'],
  template: `<div> Piece {{ number }} </div>`
})

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: { piece },
  data() {
    return {
      counter: 0,
      pieces: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addPiece() {
      this.pieces.push(this.counter)
      this.counter++
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button type="button" @click="addPiece">Add Piece</button>
  <hr>
  <Piece v-for="piece in pieces" :key="piece" :number="piece"/>
</div>
```